# Discord.js message.reference.content

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can we get which user used a command, followed by replying with a message.

I want the reply message content settings like this:

```
message.reply({content: message.reference.content});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can get the messages author using the paramater `message.author`.

```
execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send(`Hello, ${message.author}!`);
}
```